# Dataweave - Globally Unique Array Elements

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Hi I have a dataweave question, I have the sample input and I want to remove the 2nd object in the 2nd array. In short, records should be unique globally.
I tried distinct and filter, however filter remove both, distinct doesn't change anything.

Input

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "books": [
      {
        "bookid": "1234",
        "title": "C#"
      },
      {
        "bookid": "5678",
        "title": "Java"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "books": [
      {
        "bookid": "4321",
        "title": "VB"
      },
      {
        "bookid": "5678",
        "title": "Java"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "books": [
      {
        "bookid": "1234",
        "title": "C#"
      },
      {
        "bookid": "5678",
        "title": "Java"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "books": [
      {
        "bookid": "4321",
        "title": "VB"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an assumption that we would be picking the first unique title and discard the remaining. Below I broke down your problem into 4 steps. First, I am adding `id` with the `books`, then remove duplicates using `distinctBy`, then group filtered list by `id` and finally, write your desired output. I am curious to see other solutions :)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var globalList =  payload flatMap ((item) -> (
    item.books map (b) -> {id: item.id,(b)}))
    distinctBy ((item) -> item.bookid)
    groupBy ((item) -> item.id) 
---
  keysOf(globalList) map ((item) ->
    {
        id: item,
        books: globalList[item] map ((book) -> book - 'id')
    
} )
```

Comment: I think you should be doing a distinctBy on bookid rather than the title.

Comment: @SalimKhan Makes sense. Updated answer to use `bookid` in disinctBy function

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Imtiyaz's approach , just that its a bit more elaborated upon.

**Input**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "books": [
      {
        "bookid": "1234",
        "title": "C#"
      },
      {
        "bookid": "5678",
        "title": "Java"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "books": [
      {
        "bookid": "4321",
        "title": "VB"
      },
      {
        "bookid": "1234",
        "title": "Java"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "books": [
      {
        "bookid": "4321",
        "title": "VB"
      },
      {
        "bookid": "5890",
        "title": "Java"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var allBookandIds = payload flatMap (value1,index1) -> (
     value1.books map (value,index) -> {
         a: {b: value1.id, (value)}
     }.a 
) 
---
allBookandIds distinctBy($.bookid) groupBy($.b) mapObject {
    id: ($$),
    books: $ map {
        bookid: $.bookid,
        title: $.title
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "books": [
    {
      "bookid": "1234",
      "title": "C#"
    },
    {
      "bookid": "5678",
      "title": "Java"
    }
  ],
  "id": "2",
  "books": [
    {
      "bookid": "4321",
      "title": "VB"
    }
  ],
  "id": "3",
  "books": [
    {
      "bookid": "5890",
      "title": "Java"
    }
  ]
}
```